# Создать проще столько объектов String сколько столбцов в разных таблицах JTable

Tags: java

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы `Object[] row` заполнялось таким количеством столбцов, какое имеется в запрашиваемой таблице.

`headers.size() = 7`, поэтому `rs.getString(i++)` написано 7 раз. Меньше можно, больше - ошибка.

Как написать код так, чтобы не надо было создавать вручную столько `rs.getString(i++)`, сколько столбцов в другой таблице базы данных?

```java
static void select() {
    try {
    PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("select * from " + table_name);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int i = 1;
        Object[] row = new Object[]{
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++),
                rs.getString(i++)
        };
        Gui.model.addRow(row);
    }
    } catch () {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); // Получаем число столбцов

Object[] arr = new Object[columnCount];
Arrays.setAll(arr, x -> rs.getString(x)); // Заполняем массив
```

Comment: Если что, в данном случае нумерация будет начинаться с нуля. Чтобы она начиналась с единицы, вместо функции выше пиши `x -> rs.getString(x + 1)`

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!! :)